# Splitting production/development databases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express, mongoose

I'm working on a mongoDB backed expressjs app. I've used the express generator to create it.

I would really like to work on a development database through MongoLab, and then deploy to Heroku (which would also be backed by a MongoLab database).

What are the best practices for splitting these two up so when I start the app in development mode it uses the development mongo instance, and when I deploy to heroku in production mode it will use the production DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's 12Factor architecture document does a great job of explaining both the best practices of config management, and the rationale behind them:

- http://12factor.net/config

The tldr is, "pull in config from environment variables and use explicit configuration instead of named environments like 'development' or 'production.'"

Heroku will provide all the environment variables you need for connecting to your mongolab db, so all you have to sort out is providing those same variables to your app locally. One common solution is the `.env` file:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#copy-heroku-config-vars-to-your-local-env-file

This is essentially a file that you don't check in, which provides a list of key-value pairs for your local environment variables. It can be run through Heroku Local or, more generally, via tools like node-foreman or docker-compose.

*disclosure: I'm the Node.js platform owner at Heroku*